# set tab in new window using window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two pages name one.php and two.php in one.php i have a combo box which has a option values like

```
option  value='0'
option  value='1'
option  value='2'
option value ='3'
```

Now when on change event of combo box fires i am opening one new window named 'two' as follows

```
$('#sel').live('change',function(){

var tindex=$(this).val();

//Open a new window and pass tab index 

window.open('two.php#tabs-'+tindex,'two');

});
```

for the first time new window is opened correctly and ui tab is set accordingly but if i chose another value in combo box lets say '1' then url in a same new window is changed but tab is not set accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a reference to the `window` object returned by `open`, to get the `window` object for the popup.

You can then make a function in the popup window that changes the current tab, and call that function from the main window.

For example:

```
var popup = window.open('two.php#tabs-'+tindex,'two');
popup.setActiveTab(tindex);
```

In the popup window, you can write

```
window.setActiveTab = function(newIndex) {
    //Do something
};
```